# What should be behind ARPAUTHORIZEDCDFPREFIX?

Tags: windows-installer, upgrade

I've seen that you can specify an "upgrade channel" in MSI files. Is that supposed to be a human readable web page (i.e. all you get is a link in Installed Programs), or should this be a machine readable resource pointing at the latest version somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked in the registry on my computer and all entries for this property are empty. It seems the property is used by an obsolete Microsoft technology and the MSDN page states that as of IE7, it should no longer be used: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741201(v=vs.85).aspx

Personally I would leave this property undefined unless you get any validation errors on your MSI by doing so. The less you define, the less side effects you generally get. Microsoft is big on hidden compatibility "features", the more you try to deal with this by overriding things yourself the more you bang your head against the method of their madness.

Comment: I see. Perhaps my question should have been "is there a generally unobtrusive way to distribute updates for my application to interested users?".

Comment: Usually the solution for that is an Updater application or handling updates from withing the application. Windows Installer doesn't offer support for this. You need to use a third party tool or modify your application.